# How to store values to container? c++

Tags: c++, class, oop

I'am trying to save the values to container, but `add` identidier not found.
I can not also call function `Array::add(*train)`

> Error C2352   'Array::add': illegal call of non-static member function

```
Train* train = new Train(number, path, time_of_departure);
train->print();
add(*train);

//void contains();
return train;
```

Container

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Array.h"
//#include <vector>

using namespace std;
Array::Array() {}

    void  Array::add(Train &train)
    {
        trains.push_back(train);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Full code: https://github.com/brenqP/stack50/tree/process/500

Comment: Please provide a [mre] within the question without relying on external links

Comment: `Train* train = new Train(number, path, time_of_departure); ... add(*train);` This is incorrect use of `new` and pointers, please review the chapter on pointers in your C++ textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error msg suggest, you are calling the add msg like it were static
what you instead have to do is use the object and call add method

your custom class array looks like this:

```
class Array
{
private:
    vector<Train>trains;
public:
    Array();
    void  add(Train&train);
    Train find();
};
```

so you can do something like:

```
{
    Array x;
    x.add(*train)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Illegal call of non-static member function means that you are trying to call the function without using an object of the class that contains the function.